# Getting an error "throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name); MissingSchemaError: "

Tags: mongoose

I am getting this error while running the app
I have tried changing few things but nothing is really working and the application is getting crashed and is not running.

```
throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at new MissingSchemaError (C:\Users\SMIT\Desktop\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\missingSchema.js:20:11)
    at Mongoose.model (C:\Users\SMIT\Desktop\project\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:378:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SMIT\Desktop\project\model\User.js:21:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SMIT\Desktop\project\route\api\user.js:4:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This is the main file
C:\Users\SMIT\Desktop\project\index.js

```
const express= require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const user=require('./route/api/user');
const userprofile=require('./route/api/userprofile');


const app=express();
//body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//database confid into variable using variable name that I used in key.js of config folder
const database=require('./config/key').mongoURI;

//connecting to mongodb
//.then will print connected if successful
//catch will print error if not
mongoose.connect(database).then(()=>console.log("connected")).catch(err=>console.log(err));

//will give this output if successful
app.get('/',(req,res)=>res.send("testing!123"));

//gave port number 3000 input to run


//using route to check the output of user.js and userprofile.sj
app.use('/api/user',user);
app.use('/api/userprofile',userprofile);
//will run at 3000 port on localhost
const port=process.env.PORT || 3000;

//it will print this in the terminal after npm start or npm run server 
//this will print the consr port in conlsole
app.listen(port,()=> console.log('port is:: ${port}'));
```

C:\Users\SMIT\Desktop\project\model/User.js

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const Schema=mongoose.Schema;

//creating schema for users
const UserSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }

});

module.exports=user=mongoose.model('User','UserSchema');
```

C:\Users\SMIT\Desktop\project\route\api\user.js

```
const express=require('express');
const router=express.Router();
const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');
const user=require('../../model/User');

router.get('/demo',(req,res)=>res.json({output:"user"}));

//creating route for regsiteration

router.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    //find if email exists or not.
    user.findOne({email: req.body.email}).then(user=>{
        if(user){
            return res.status(400).json({email:"email is already registered"});
        }
        else{
            //else will creaete new user
            const newUser=new User({
                name: req.body.name,
                email:req.body.email,
                password:req.body.password
            })

            //generate salt and hash pass with salt
            bcrypt.genSalt(10,()=>{
                //hashing password
                bcrypt.hash(newuser.password, salt, (err,hash)=>{
                    if(err)
                    throw err;
                    newUser.password=hash;
                    newUser.save()
                    .then(user=>res.json())

                })
            })
        }
    })
});
module.exports=router;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your file '**C:\Users\SMIT\Desktop\project\model/User.js**' export variable like this

```
var User = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
module.exports = {User};
```

hopefully it would resolve the issue